# Function sqlite3_open instead of opening the db file, it creates one

Tags: c, sqlite

i have the following code and when I compile it in terminal it returns the message "SQL error".I think the function sqlite3_open doesn't open the database but instead create a new one everytime and the function callback isn't called.OS is macos.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sqlite3.h>
static int my_special_callback(void *unused, int count, char **data, char **columns)
{
    int idx;

    printf("There are %d column(s)\n", count);

    for (idx = 0; idx < count; idx++) {
        printf("The data in column \"%s\" is: %s\n", columns[idx], data[idx]);
    }

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    sqlite3* db;

    int rc = sqlite3_open ("test.db", &db); 

    if (rc)                                        
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg (db));
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        printf("DB\n");
    }

   rc = sqlite3_exec(db, "SELECT * FROM user", my_special_callback, 0, NULL);
    if( rc != SQLITE_OK ) {
       fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: \n");
    } else {
       fprintf(stdout, "Operation done successfully\n");
    }

    sqlite3_close(db);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should print out useful error messages every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing wrong with your program, except maybe in my_special_callback.
Use another program for example DB BROWSER FOR SQLITE , now open test.db that your program just created , please add the table user and add a few fields, save what you just created, run your program, it'll work. On your previous attempts you probably forgot to copy back the db where you had the table created, and your program does not create the table if it is not there.